# How can I output an error in Javascript that is visible in the debugger, without halting the flow of my program?

Tags: javascript, console

At the moment, if a developer implements something and forgets to create a template for it in Javascript, there is an error and the whole control I am writing breaks. I am about to add some error checking that will stop it breaking, but I would still like to output something to the console so a developer can see the problem, rather than have the item simply not appear and leave them scratching their head.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [exception handling](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/trycatch.shtml) in conjunction with JavaScript logger, such as [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/).